# KSH, read used in a pipeline

Tags: ksh, pipeline, heredoc

I'm trying to learn Here Documents IO-redirections in Korn Shell.
I used "read" builtin to test the concepts.

**I wrote a sample program as follows**

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

cat << ONE | wc -l | read word | if [ $word -eq 1 ]; then cat << TWO ; fi  | wc -l | read word | if [ $word -eq 2 ]; then cat << THREE ; fi 
1
ONE
1
2
TWO
1
2
3
THREE
```

I expect the output to be:

```
1
2
3
```

But the output is

```
[: argument expected
```

i think the $word variable is empty.

**Then i rewrote the program as below which works fine:**

```
cat << ONE | wc -l | { read word ; if [ $word -eq 1 ]; then cat << TWO ; fi ;} | wc -l | { read word ; if [ $word -eq 2 ]; then cat << THREE ; fi ;}
1
ONE
1
2
TWO
1
2
3
THREE
```

The output is as expected:

```
1
2
3
```

My question is about the first snippet:

- why the "read word" command in the pipeline is not updating the word
  variable in the shell and the subsequent commands are not able to use
  it.
- Also 'read word" doesn't write anything to the standard output so
  using it in a pipeline is not right, but i wanted to check it out.
- But then, the command following the "read word" doesn't read anything
  from standard input so it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that each side of a pipe (`|`) is a separate shell session.

In your first attempt you have `... | wc -l | read word | if ...`, so while the result of `wc -l` will be read and stored in the next shell session's variable `word`, this variable is not passed to the next shell session.  And since the variable `word` is now undefined, your statement `if [ $word -eq 1 ]` becomes `if [  -eq -1 ]` and hence the error.

In your second attempt your `{ read word ; if [ $word -eq 1 ]; then cat << TWO ; fi ;}` construct represents a single shell session where the variable `word` is initialized (with the results of `wc -l`), and because this is still a single shell the variable can now be used in your `if/then` block.

Comment: But if each command in a pipeline is separate environment, how is the below one possible ? `abi@linux-lat4:/home/abi> echo 1 | read one  
abi@linux-lat4:/home/abi> echo $one 
1`   echo $one is displaying 1 in the invoking shell.. How come the variable assigned in a shell in the pipeline is accessible from the main shell

Comment: what does `one=2 ; echo 1 | read one ; echo $one` return?  what shell are you using for your command line?

Comment: I'm using ksh as my login shell.. Just to make sure that the shell doesn't have any parameter as one set to 1, I created a new login shell and executed that command..

Comment: I just found that in a pipeline , the last command can possibly be executed in the same environment and ksh does not need to execute the last command in a separate session. so that explains my question. `Reference -
 The New Korn Shell - David G. Korn `

Comment: depends on the implementation of the shell, eg, you'll get different results between cygwin (mksh) vs linux (which can vary based on linux implementation)